# Kali Linux login screen stuck in Virtual Machine

Tags: linux, virtualbox

I have installed 32 bit Kali linux on a virtual machine and I keep getting stuck on the login screen, it asks for my login information. I type "root, enter, then the password I set during the graphical installation." Nothing happens no changes no blinks just the same old login screen that has been there for over an hour. I am completely new to this sort of operating system and I have no clue what the problem is I am also new to linux on a virtual machine. I am running windows 10 and using Virtual Box.

Comment: So basically when you hit Enter, nothing happens?